# No matching NodeSelectorTerms

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Until yesterday this used to work, we are able to create a new set of pods under a namespace. However, today any new deployment fails to mount the PVC and I have no idea why.

How can I investigate this further, nothing was changed meanwhile.

```
kubectl describe pods --namespace 29df2a1c-5d75-4b8b-ae17-b98cfb291496
```

> Warning  FailedMount  44s   kubelet  MountVolume.NodeAffinity check failed for volume "pvc-c0e7b110-c7d3-4f21-ad5d-8ff116047442" : No matching NodeSelectorTerms

Comment: Which version of kubernetes do you have?

Comment: I was running 1.16. When I upgraded to 1.21 the problem was solved

Comment: I am glad to read it was resolved, can you please [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading your kubernetes version was requested based on the error message you shared. I found that the issue could be related to this bug: [kubernetes/kubernetes#69928](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/69928) which was fixed in v1.14: [kubernetes/kubernetes#70026](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/70026), this is why the upgrade was the best option to resolve it as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/).